# Are there any published values for GPIO slew rate or rise/fall times on ESP32?

Tags: esp32, specifications, rise-time, slew-rate

Are there any published values for GPIO slew rate or rise/fall times on ESP32? I had a look at the datasheets and couldn't find any. I also couldn't find any measurements elsewhere. Have Espressif published them somewhere other than the datasheet? If not, has anyone measured and publicly documented them?

Comment: I would look to the datasheet for the specific processor. Not just a vague *ESP32*, which isn't going to spec that. That information will be, if it is to be found at all, in the Electrical Specifications of the specific CPU chip. If you know what the chip is, search for the datasheet and provide us with a link to it. Most of us know where to find such things, quickly, if they are there at all. If lucky it will only a worst-case figure. So you will only know things are 'better' but you won't know by how much. I know I've never seen both typical and worst case on the same sheet, though.

Comment: @jonk Yeah, I checked for a bunch of the ESP32 chips, no specs in the datasheets. I'm not new to this, I just couldn't find the t_r/t_f numbers anywhere despite a fairly thorough search. I was hoping someone had characterised any one of the common ESP32 chips so I could at least get a ballpark.

Comment: Then I would tend to guess the rise and fall times (the sum of the two) will be about 25% of the fastest allowable clock rate. That's been the experience I've seen on the rare occasions I've cared to measure a few. Measuring here would be nicer than guessing. But even then you'd need to measure a few dozen, I think, to get sufficient confidence. You could always contact the CPU manufacturer, I suppose.

Comment: It is complicated by the fact that the drive strengths are programmable. It can be approximated by: \$\Delta t = \frac{C \Delta V}{I}\$  20 pF, 3V, 20 mA -> 3 nS

Comment: See page 72 for "drive strength" , 2 Bits labelled "FUN_DRV", default 0 ...  https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf#iomuxgpio

Comment: See https://e2e.ti.com/support/logic-group/logic/f/logic-forum/718814/faq-what-is-the-output-transition-rate-for-a-logic-device.

Comment: And just measured? Put a gpio in pwm mode (led pwm lib) and you can make a square wave signal  0-40Mhz. With an oscilloscope you can measure both, most can do this automatically.